# Navigation parameter is undefined

Tags: react-native

I am trying to pass a parameter by navigation screen. But when I receive the parameter at child screen it gives me undefined.

```
Parent Screen : 
navigate('Screen2', {itemId: 'sales'})
```

Screen2

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const id = navigation.getParam('itemId');
console.log(id);
```

Result :

> Undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```js
const { id } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
console.log(id);

OR

const id  = this.props.navigation.state.params.id;
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works!

```js
Parent Screen
    this.props.navigation.push('Screen2', {itemId: 'sales'});


Screen2
    const { id } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    console.log(id);

//Hope you're using react-navigation
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, the way you are using getParams method is incorrect. Try following:

```
const id = this.props.navigation.getParam('itemId', 'defaultId');
```

Or else you can also use solutions by @Jothi Basu & @hong develop.

Answer (score 0):

Use navigate.state.params

Screen2:

`const id = this.props.navigation.state.params.itemId`